# Считать информацию из всех файлов в папке

Tags: c++, файлы

Задача стоит следующим образом. У меня имеется N файлов в папке, надо при вызове функции считать информацию из первого файла, и при последующих вызовах чтобы функция читала информацию из следующего файла который есть в папке.

Например есть условная папка с условными файлами:

- Level1
- Level2
- Level3

Я вызываю функцию, она считывает информацию из файла Level1, следующий раз вызываю считывает информацию из Level2 и так далее пока не кончатся файлы.

Comment: Ну так добавляете в функцию статическую переменную, которая запоминает последний считанный файл - и дело в шляпе...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::filesystem;

bool doFile() {
    static directory_iterator di(".");
    static auto it = begin(di);

    if (it == end(di)) return false;


    // Работа с it
    cout << it->path() << endl;


    it++;
    return true;
    }
```

Если функция вернула `false` - файлы закончились. Простейший пример - `while(doFile());`

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, никто Вас (а самое главное, чтобы и Вы сами) не ограничивает в стандарте С++, и Вы, как современный адекватный программист С++, будете использовать, как минимум, С++17.
Так вот в С++ можно сделать так:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
        
int main() {
std::string path = "/path/to/directory"; // Путь к папке
for (const auto& entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
    std::cout << entry.path() << std::endl;
}
```

Благодаря entry.path() ты получаешь путь к файлу в папке, который можно считать уже любым известным тебе способом, например, через модуль `<fstream>`. И никаких статических переменных в функции не надо, все файлы просто в цикле пройдутся и всё. Однако стоит заметить, что [directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) не посещает подкаталоги. Для посещения всех подкаталогов нужен [recursive_directory_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator)

Comment: Если я понял вопрос верно, то нужен не циклический проход, а именно обработка по одному файлу в момент вызова функции. Время от времени, в промежутке - куча разной работы. Так, как вы пишете, можно - но тогда очень усложнится сам цикл, поскольку всю работу программы надо будет втискивать в итерации.

Comment: @Mikhailo, ну если обработка нужна какая-то синхронная, в определённый момент времени, то, конечно, можно и со статической переменной. Хотя этот цикл можно запустить в потоке и просто при помощи std::condition_variable приостанавливать, когда обработка файла не нужна, тут уже индивидуально))

Comment: Исходное условие (выделено мною): *надо **при вызове функции** считать информацию из первого файла, и **при последующих вызовах** чтобы **функция читала** информацию из следующего файла который есть в папке*. Я ориентируюсь на этот текст. Иначе получится как в том анекдоте про суровую жену - мол, у мужа есть собственное мнение, но оно не отличается от моего.